# How does python infinite bit representation works?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, operators, bit, infinite

I am learning python recently and have read about infinite bit representation of integers in python, but did not actually understand the technology or math behind it. So anyone here knows how does it work?

I have read about it through this link while studying bitwise operators:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know exactly how it's implemented in Python, what's important is the recognition that although *arbitrarily large* integers can be handled in Python, it can't handle infinite numbers. So the wiki is a little misleading.

Any integer is finite and can be expressed in a finite form. So one way to deal with it is to have the convention that the first bit in the array is what is repeated infinitely. For example:

```
-5 = 11111011 = ...1111111011
+3 = 00000011 = ...0000000011
```

Where for these examples, I showed the fixed 8-bit representation of each number along with its "infinite" representation.

These are basically [BitArrays](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitArrays) from which we can then implement arithmetic on top of.

Comment: Oh, Thanks a lot. That was so helpful.